# Why I can't use Hooks in React class components' render method

Tags: reactjs

In my mental model, React function components are basically class components stripped down to `render` method (and this is reinforced by React docs saying that that `render` should be a pure function of state and props). I assume that `render` method and Functional components are called at the same phase of React lifecycle so why I can't use hooks in `render` method? To be more precise, I want to know the technical limitations of class components which disallow hooks usage.

```
import React from "react";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const [state, setState] = React.useState(0); // Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: class component are classes, functional components are functions, so developers decided to make for classes lifecycle methods, but for functions hooks. Under the hood, functions component works just with hooks, this is a rule and we have to accept it. `I want to know the technical limitations of class components which disallow hooks usage`, do you want to know the part of the code from react `core` code that does not allow using hooks in class components? Am i right?

Comment: I want to know if it's technically possible to use hooks in the `render` method

Answer (score -4):

no, we can't use hooks with class component. So, please, read the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper)

Rules of hooks:

- ✅ ***Call Hooks from React function components.***
- ✅ Call Hooks from custom Hooks (we’ll learn about them on the next page).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what I'm loking for is the technical or design limitation which forbids using hooks in class components. I'm aware I can't use it that way so I want to know why

Comment: @dkuznietsov, because developers decided to make a difference between classs components and functional components. For class components they created lifecycle methods and for functional components hooks, very simple. This is just a way to make a difference between this 2 way of creating components. If they would use the same idea, what would be the difference between class and functional components?! The idea is that every think is used for a scope.